# gwt-gwt 3.0 file upload issue with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, gxt

I'm having a problem getting the file object when I use FormPanel, FileUploadField, and Spring.

Here is what I have:

I added the CommonsMultipartResolver bean to my Spring Context file:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
   <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

I have a model class with the regular getters and setters:

```
pulic class UploadItem{
  private String filename;
  private CommonsMultipartFile fileData;
  ....
  getters/setters
  ....
}
```

My controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Foo")
public class ThingController extends BaseController implements ServlerContextAware{
  ....
  @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody
  String createFile(UploadItem item, BindingResults results){
     String orgFile = item.getFileData().getOriginalFilename();
     return orgFile;
  }
```

I'm using UiBinding to create the form fields, but I'm calling the fileupload field and formpanel to add the other methods in code.

I have a submit button that calls:

```
  form.submit();
```

And my constructor I take care of the other form requirements:

```
  form.setMethod(Method.POST);
  form.setEncoding(Encoding.MULTIPART);
  form.setAction("http://url.com/foo/bar");
  form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler(){
     @Override
     public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event){
          String results = event.getResults();
          Info.display("Upload Response", results);
     }
  });
```

When I run the code I get a nullpointerexecption on item.getFileData().getOriginalFilename();

I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the form isn't bound to the UploadItem, because you never told Spring to do that. Now, I am hoping that someone knows how to do this. Normally I would use Spring's form tag library and provide a modelAttribute or commandName in the form, but since I (and the ts) use GWT the form is built from GWT components and I can't use Spring form tags.